# Why I get OutOfMemoryException when generating parser tree with ANTLR?

Tags: c#, antlr

I built a "simples" grammar to interprete a file that looks like a json (or xml). But, when I try to parse the file and navigate on the tree I get a `System.OutOfMemoryException`.

The input file have just 108MB but contains almost 5 millions lines.

Here is a sample of the file:

```
(
    :field ("ObjectName"
        :field (
            :field ("{6BF621F9-A0E2-49BB-A86B-3DE4750954F4}")
            :field (Value)
            :field (Value)
            :field (
                :Time ("Sun Jan 26 10:08:33 2014")
                :last_modified_utc (1390730913)
                :By ("Some text")
                :From (localhost)
            )
            :field ("text/text")
            :field (false)
            :field (false)
        )
        :field ()
        :field ()
        :field ()
        :field (0)
        :field (true)
        :field (true)
    )
.
.
.
.
.
)
```

Following the grammar:

```
grammar Objects;

/*
 * Parser Rules
 */


compileUnit
    : obj
    ;


obj
    : OPEN ID? (field)* CLOSE
    ;

field
    : ':'(ID)? obj
    ;


/*
 * Lexer Rules
 */


OPEN 
    : '(' 
    ;

CLOSE 
    : ')' 
    ;

ID
    : (ALPHA | ALPHA_IN_STRING)
    ;


fragment
INT_ID
    : ('0'..'9')
    ;

fragment
ALPHA_EACH
    : 'A'..'Z' | 'a'..'z' | '_' | INT_ID | '-' | '.' | '@'
    ;

fragment
ALPHA
    : (ALPHA_EACH)+
    ;

fragment
ALPHA_IN_STRING
    : ('"' ( ~[\r\n] )+ '"')
    ;



WS
    // :    ' ' -> channel(HIDDEN)
    : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip  // skip spaces, tabs, newlines
    ;
```

And the parser:

```
var input = new Antlr4.Runtime.AntlrInputStream(text);
var lexer = new ObjectsLexer(input);
var tokens = new Antlr4.Runtime.CommonTokenStream(lexer);
var parser = new ObjectsParser(tokens);

// Context for the compileUnit rule
// ERROR: Here I got the error. When start the to build the tree for compileUnit rule
var ctx = parser.compileUnit();


// The following line is not executed
new ObjectsVisitor().Visit(ctx);
```

On the error line, I realise that the memory growth exponentialy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- If the input is UTF-8 encoded and uses primarily ASCII characters, the conversion to UTF-16 will require approximately 216MB.
- Each token uses at least 48 bytes of memory.
- Each token which appears in the parse tree uses at least 20 bytes of memory (in addition to the 44).
- Each rule node in the parse tree uses at least 36 bytes of memory. If the rule has any children, the minimum is 68 bytes.

The numbers above do not include any locals, arguments, labels, or return values, all of which are stored in the tree if you use them.

Assuming 4 characters per token, half the tokens in the parse tree, and an average of 3 tokens per parse tree node (completely arbitrary values here), you get:

- Input: 216MB
- ~28 million tokens: ~1281MB
- ~14 million terminal nodes in the parse tree: ~267MB
- ~4.7 million parse tree nodes: ~308MB

This is over 2GB memory, and doesn't count any of the overhead associated with the runtime or the dynamic DFA cache constructed internally by ANTLR. You will clearly need to either run your application as a 64-bit process or reduce the size of your inputs.

Comment: If I had a big XML file, like that with 5 millions lines, ANTLR won't be the best tool to read/interpret it, is it? In this case, should I make something a part, without ANTLR?

Comment: Any way of clearing the cache? I know this is not ideal, but running out of memory isn't ideal either :-(